VS Code with Vue shows me: Property '' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
In Visual Studio Code, I have the following code:
<script lang="ts" setup>

const parseCSV = () => {
     // Code omitted for brevity
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="parseCSV">Parse</button>
</template>

The IDE shows me a squiggly line under parseCSV. The message shown is:

Property 'parseCSV' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

What is the reason?

Restarting the extension "Vue - Official" helped me solve this problem.
I did it like so:

Open Extensions View: You can open the Extensions view by clicking on the square icon on the sidebar or pressing Ctrl+Shift+X.
Find the Vue Official Extension: Type "Vue Official" into the search bar in the Extensions view.
Disable and Re-enable: Click on Disable to temporarily turn off the extension. Then, click on Enable to restart it.


Please mark your question as accepted.
